# Laravel: Update multiple rows using find()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following eloquent code:

```
$gifts = FriendGift::find($collectedGifts); // An array of IDS
```

I want to set all as `collected = 1`.

I tried this:

```
$gifts->update(['collected' => 1]);
```

but I get the following error:

```
Method update does not exist
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the model and do a mass update like this:

```
FriendGift::whereIn('id', $collectedGifts)->update(['collected' => 1]);
```

Comment: Your answer would be perfect if you also answer the actual question, which is "what's wrong" and @lagbox explained beautifully.

Comment: I cannot copy/repeat his answer. He already said what's wrong... next step is usually "how can I fix that"?

Answer (score 7):

You are not calling `update` on a Model. You are calling `update` on an Eloquent Collection which doesn't have a method `update`.

Answer (score 0):

If $collectedGifts is an Array, its not gonna work. Model::find() is waiting for a simple id, not an array.

Anyways, i prefer using the save method of an element if i want to update a field.
So you just get the Row you want, assign some value to it, and then save the instance.
For example:

```
$gifts = FriendGifts::find(15);//This is just 1 gift
$gifts->collected = 1;
$gifts->save();
```

For multiple gifts:

```
$gifts = FriedGifts::where('id',15)->get();
foreach($gifts as $one_gift){
    $one_gift->collected = 1;
    $one_gift->save();
}
```

Or something like that!

Hope this helps!
Good luck!